# Override Magento persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Tags: magento, templates, checkout, persistent, billing

I need to override Magento **"checkout onepage billing"** (Block and phtml).

I extended the block (Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing) correctly but I can't replace the **"persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"** with my custom billing.phtml. I need it to add some new fields and edit existing fields without edit base core files, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To override this file  you need to create a copy of it in your own package. Would be something like this:

**app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

Congrats for the question. Never update ANY files in base/default.